# After updating Gazebo to 1.3 under Groovy I get an Ogre Plugin error

Tags: gazebo, ogre, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS Groovy and I updated Gazebo to 1.3 (binary version), under Ubuntu 12.04.

For testing it I got a simple **empty.world**:

```
<?xml version ='1.0'?>
<sdf version ='1.3'>
  <world name='default'>
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>

  </world>
</sdf>
```

After I *source*:

`/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo-1.3/setup.sh`
`/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/setup.bash`

and run *gzserver*:

`rosrun gazebo gzserver ~/../worlds/empty.world`

I got the following error msg:

```
Error [RenderEngine.cc:374] Unable to load Ogre Plugin[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL]. Rendering will not be possible.Make sure you have installed OGRE and Gazebo properly.
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find OpenGL rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.
```

Did something happen to the OpenGL libraries during the update, or is this a bug?

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1125/after-updating-gazebo-to-1.3-under-groovy-i-get-an-ogre-plugin-error/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solution: in 
 *`/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazeb/setup.bash`*

 I had to change the `OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH` to:

 *`export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4`*

UPDATE: according to @Ryan:

on Ubuntu 11.10, change `OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH` to `/usr/lib/OGRE` in both

```
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/setup.bash
```

and

```
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/setup.sh
```

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, Andrei

I had the same error too. I have found that OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH was not correct.
There was a row

```
export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4
```

in file /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/setup.sh
However, folder [x86_64-linux-gnu] is empty on my computer. I have found OGRE-1.7.4 in folder [/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu], so I replace the row on following row:

```
export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4
```

Now I have not this error.

Best Regards,
Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alex Buyval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182/alex-buyval/) with karma: 31 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-05**:
Hi Alex, thanks for answering, for me the solution it doesn't work. I actually have the libraries in x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4. I will try a reinstall.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-05**:
I figured it out thanks to your answer, I had a different path in the setup.sh, which changed with the update. And I guess you had to change it to i386-linux-gnu because you are running on 32 bits.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/300/destogl/) on 2013-04-08**:
Thanks! Works for 32 bit 12.04 Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 at the moment. I needed to change OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH to /usr/lib/OGRE in both

/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/setup.bash

and

/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/setup.sh

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27/ryan/) with karma: 21 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2013-05-14**:
Thanks, it helped.